# What is the difference between fully observed and partially observed state features in Reinforcement learning ?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

When we use a function to approximate Q values or policy to state-action pairs we hear the above two terms **fully and partially observed features**. what is the difference . Normally in Atari Games they generate Q values by taking the current pixels distribution of the frame .

Comment: I have heard of partially observed state, but not entirely sure about partially observed features. They are probably the same thing, but just using a different phrase - could you give a reference to where you saw the term used?

Comment: Well you are right . I referring to partially observed state features . Technically states .

Comment: Could you give a reference to where you have seen "partially observed state features" please? I need to see the phrase in context to understand the correct answer. My concern is that it might be a different thing to "partially observed state", and I want to answer accurately.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5602.pdf paper . Here in the background section second paragraph they mentioned about the partially observed pixels in frame. Not explicitly saying features . Since those pixels are feature I used the work when asking the question .

Comment: There is no mention of "partially observed pixels" in the paper. The only relevant phrase I see is "Since the agent only observes images of the current screen, the task is partially observed and many emulator states are perceptually aliased"  - is that what you are referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fully observed state means that there is no hidden information. Clear examples of this are chess and Go because both players have all the information. The fact that both these games are deterministic doesn't matter. A game where the state changes are stochastic can still be fully observable. Games like poker, where both players can observe their own hand but not their opponents' are called partially observable. Other examples of this can be real time strategy games like Starcraft where you can only see in the line of sight of your units.